# Java 8 stream groupingBy: summing an attributeValue

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I have a simple class Foo:

```
class Foo {
   String type; 
   Integer quantity;
   String code;
   //...
}
```

and a list of objects of that type:

```
{ type=11, quantity=1, code=A },
{ type=11, quantity=2, code=A },
{ type=11, quantity=1, code=B },
{ type=11, quantity=3, code=C },
{ type=12, quantity=2, code=A },
{ type=12, quantity=1, code=B },
{ type=11, quantity=1, code=B },
{ type=13, quantity=1, code=C },
{ type=13, quantity=3, code=C }
```

I need to first group by type, and I can do that:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> typeGroups = mylist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getType));
```

The next step would be transforming that `Map` to a `List<Foo>` like this:

```
{ type=11, quantity=3, code=A },
{ type=11, quantity=2, code=B },
{ type=11, quantity=3, code=C },
{ type=12, quantity=2, code=A },
{ type=12, quantity=1, code=B },
{ type=13, quantity=4, code=C }
```

In SQL, I'd have this kind of query:

```
SELECT type, code, SUM(quantity) FROM Foo GROUP BY type, code
```

Let me explain in plain english, too.

I need to end up with a List of Foos. Each one's code must be unique among its group, and quantity must be the aggregate sum of Foos having same code among their group.

I tried doing that using `groupingBy()` with `summingInt()` but can't get the desired result.

Comment: Why is `quantity` a `String`, and what are the results you're expecting?

Comment: sorry David, wrong copy&paste :)) 
I am expecting to obtain the second list, in the code boxes

Comment: It looks like you want to group by type *and code*. That's the first thing to address.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's exactly what I want. I can group multilevel, but my 'value' should be a Map<String, Map<String, Foo>>. 
NOT a Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>.
I simply don't know how to write the reduction for a single attribute inside an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `groupingBy` collector that groups according to a list made by the `type` and the `code`. This works because two lists are equal when all of their elements are equal and in the same order. (Note that the list here only serves as a container of values with an equality defined as equality of all the values contained and in the same order; a custom `Tuple` class would also work here).

The following code first creates an intermediate map `Map<List<String>, Integer>` where the key corresponds to a list of type and code and the value corresponds to the sum of all the quantities for those type and code. That map is then post-processed: each entry are mapped to a `Foo` where the `type` is the first value of the key, the `quantity` is the value and the `code` is the second value of the key.

```
Map<List<String>, Integer> map = 
    myList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             f -> Arrays.asList(f.getType(), f.getCode()),
             Collectors.summingInt(Foo::getQuantity)
          ));

List<Foo> result = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(e -> new Foo(e.getKey().get(0), e.getValue(), e.getKey().get(1)))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Notice that the above solution is using 2 different Stream pipelines. This could be done using a single Stream pipeline but it would require a collector that is capable of collecting into 2 different collectors. In this case, the first collector would just keep the first grouped value and the second one would sum the quantities. Unfortunately, there are no such collectors in the Stream API itself. This can be done using the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library that contains such a collector.

In the following code, the input list is still grouped by a list formed by the type and code of the `Foo`. What changes is the collector: we're using [`pairing(c1, c2, finisher)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-) that pairs two collectors and applies the given finisher operation on the result of the collectors.

- The first collector here is simply [`first()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#first--) that returns the first grouped `Foo` (we don't need the others as we know they will have the same type and code). It is wrapped with a call to [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to extract the `Optional` value out of the `first()` collector (`first()` returns an `Optional` to handle the case where the stream is empty and would collect into an empty `Optional`; this is not possible here so we can call `get()` safely).
- The second collector simply sums all the quantities with [`summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).
- The finisher operation here combines the `Foo` returned by the first collector and the result of the summation into a new `Foo` with the new quantity.

Finally, we only need to keep the values of the resulting map. Since [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) returns a `Collection`, it is wrapped into a `ArrayList` to have the final result.

```
List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>(
    myList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
              f -> Arrays.<String>asList(f.getType(), f.getCode()),
              MoreCollectors.pairing(
                 Collectors.collectingAndThen(MoreCollectors.first(), Optional::get),
                 Collectors.summingInt(Foo::getQuantity),
                 (f, s) -> new Foo(f.getType(), s, f.getCode())
              )
          )).values());
```

Comment: I would use a `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instead of `Arrays.asList` to store the keys in the first step. That would give some extra type information.

Comment: @Lii The snippet above is also type-safe. As I said the list here is just a container, you can roll your own container if you want. Also, I wouldn't really recommend using `SimpleEntry` for this: first it only handles 2 values (when we could want to support more) and I feel using it here is more of an abuse of not having a true `Tuple` class.

Comment: @Lii: `SimpleEntry` can’t be scaled to support more than two keys for the group and has a misleading predefined semantic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done as follows in one go, assuming

```
public class Foo {
    private String type;
    private int quantity;
    private String code;

    public Foo(String type, int quantity, String code) {
        this.type = type;
        this.code = code;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getType() {return type;}
    public int getQuantity() {return quantity;}
    public String getCode() {return code;}
}
```

and

   `List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
   foos.add(new Foo("11", 1, "A"));
   foos.add(new Foo("11", 2, "A"));
   foos.add(new Foo("11", 1, "B"));
   foos.add(new Foo("11", 3, "C"));
   foos.add(new Foo("12", 2, "A"));
   foos.add(new Foo("12", 1, "B"));
   foos.add(new Foo("11", 1, "B"));
   foos.add(new Foo("13", 1, "C"));
   foos.add(new Foo("13", 3, "C"));`

The following

```
    foos.stream().collect(
                    toMap(
                            f -> f.getType() + f.getCode(),
                            Function.identity(),
                            (s, a) -> new Foo(
                                        s.getType(), 
                                        s.getQuantity() + a.getQuantity(),
                                        s.getCode()))
                          )
                    .values();
```

produces

```
Foo[type='12'|quantity=2|code='A'] 
Foo[type='13'|quantity=4|code='C'] 
Foo[type='12'|quantity=1|code='B'] 
Foo[type='11'|quantity=3|code='A'] 
Foo[type='11'|quantity=2|code='B'] 
Foo[type='11'|quantity=3|code='C']
```

Comment: Similar to the **rxjava** solution by @frhack but sticking to the core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

With [rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) help: groupBy + flatMap + reduce

```
    Observable.from(()->fooList.stream().iterator())
    .groupBy(f->Arrays.asList(f.type,f.code))
    .flatMap((Observable<Foo> o)->o
            .reduce((a,b)->new Foo(a.type,a.code,a.quantity+b.quantity))
    )
    .forEach((Foo o) ->
        System.out.println("type:" + o.type + " code:" + o.code +" qty:"+ o.quantity)
    )  ;
```