# Using Java Streams Map<String,List<Object>> filter specific value and convert Object to Dto

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I want to calculate the total sum of Salary by personalId.

My map is of type `Map<String, List<Employee>>`. Where employee  `id` is used a Key, while value is a list of employee instances having the same `id`.

Here is the list of map shown below

```
Id, Name , Surname, Salary
personalId1, "Name 1","Surname 1", 100
personalId2, "Name 2","Surname 2", 100
personalId3, "Name 3","Surname 3", 100
personalId1, "Name 1","Surname 1", 100
personalId2, "Name 2","Surname 2", 100
personalId2, "Name 2","Surname 2", 100
.........................
```

What I really want to get this result shown below.

```
personalId1, "Name 1","Surname 1", 200
personalId2, "Name 2","Surname 2", 300
personalId3, "Name 3","Surname 3", 100
```

Here is my dto class shown below

```
public class SalaryDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private BigDecimal totalSalary;
}
```

I tried to use java stream to get this result but I have a problem after `flatMap`. To get the total by personalId, I want to use "reduce".

Here is the code snippet shown below.

```
List<SalaryDto> totalSalary = employees.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(e-> new SalaryDto(...))
    .collect(groupingBy(Personal::getID, Collectors.toList()));
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

They're already grouped, so all you need to do is reduce each list to a single `SalaryDto`:

```
SalaryDto flatten(List<Employee> employees) {
    BigDecimal totalSalary = employees.stream()
            .map(Employee::getSalary)
            .reduce(BigDecimal::add).get();
    return SalaryDto.forEmployee(employees.get(0), totalSalary);
}
```

And now it's a simple `map` call:

```
List<SalaryDto> salaries = employees.values()
        .stream()
        .map(this::flatten)
        .collect(toMap(SalaryDto::getId, s -> s));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I group by id to sum salary and convert the object to dto?

Comment: What is forEmployee method?

Comment: It's a static factory method that accepts `(Employee, BigDecimal)`. You didn't provide any details as to how the DTO is constructed, so I used my imagination.

Comment: I asked what is the body part of forEmployee method?

Comment: It's not a real method. It's a stand-in for whatever logic you have to convert `Employee` to  `SalaryDto`. Feel free to implement it however makes sense or use whatever constructor/factory you have already have defined.

Comment: @shmosel I tried to use your approach like forEmployee but I couldn't solve my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512927/java-stream-issue-of-calculating-count-sum-of-one-value-and-multiple-group-by-c

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom accumulation type for calculating the total salary for each id (*it's a common practice to keep DTO immutable, but if you want to avoid introducing new types you can add a new behaviour into `SalaryDto` but I would not advice to do so*).

```
public class SalaryAccumulator implements Consumer<Employee> {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private BigDecimal totalSalary = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    
    public void accept(Employee e) {
        if (id == null) id = e.getId();
        if (name == null) name = e.getName();
        if (surname == null) surname = e.getSurname();
        totalSalary = totalSalary.add(e.getSalary());
    }
    
    public SalaryAccumulator merge(SalaryAccumulator other) {
        totalSalary = totalSalary.add(other.getTotalSalary());
        return this;
    }
    
    public SalaryDto toSalaryDto() {
        return new SalaryDto(id, name, surname, totalSalary);
    }
}
```

And in the stream in order to turn each `List` of `Employee` into a `SalaryDto` you can generate a stream over the list and apply `collect()` passing a custom Collector as an argument.

To define a custom Collector, we need to make of the static factory method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)). That's where `SalaryAccumulator` would come into play, it would serve as a mutable container of the collector.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employees = // initializing the map
        
List<SalaryDto> totalSalary = employees.values().stream()
    .map(list -> list.stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            SalaryAccumulator::new,
            SalaryAccumulator::accept,
            SalaryAccumulator::merge,
            SalaryAccumulator::toSalaryDto
        ))
    ).toList();
```

Alternatively, in the nested stream, we can make use of the combination of Collectors [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) and [`reducing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employees = // initializing the map
        
List<SalaryDto> totalSalary = employees.values().stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream()
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal::add),
            salary -> new SalaryDto(l.get(0).getId(),
                l.get(0).getName(),
                l.get(0).getSurname(),
                salary.orElseThrow())
        ))
    ).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use this resource (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997501/java-8-stream-groupingby-summing-an-attributevalue) but it didn't help.

Comment: @S.N Sorry, I didn't understand how the link you've posted is connected to my answer?

Comment: I don't want to use Consumer. Is it impossible to handle with that without Consumer? What I want to do is to group by id to sum salary and convert the object to dto.

Comment: @S.N Just remove it the `implements` clause.  If you've any other points of confusion?

Comment: I want to use flatMap and then map the object to dto while calculating the total amount? Which way should I use? Can you also share the information with me?

Comment: @S.N You don't need `flatMap` in this case (to understand why, try to visualize the operations by writing the required operations on a paper).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I tried to use your approach like merge but I couldn't solve my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512927/java-stream-issue-of-calculating-count-sum-of-one-value-and-multiple-group-by-c

Comment: @qwercan You're getting incorrect count `totalPerson` because you're not taking into account person `id` (i.e. you're treating each DTO in your code as representing a distinct `Person` which is not true). You can create a intermediate object maintaining a `Set` of `id` to accumulate the `Person` instances. And then turn these objects into DTO by using the `size` of their Sets of ids as the person count.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I tried to use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        p -> new GroupDto(p.getEventDate().getMonthValue(), p.getId()),
                        Collectors.counting()
                ))` before but I have problem in map part. Can you help me?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I just tried to follow your approach but I have no idea how to implement it after creating an another `DTO` containg `Set<String> personId`

Comment: @qwercan Feel free to post the question regarding this problem with your attempt.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I already asked it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512927/java-stream-issue-of-calculating-count-sum-of-one-value-and-multiple-group-by-c

Comment: @qwercan But the code **doesn't** contain the attempt you've mentioned. I would not suggest instead of editing the existing question (which invalidates the answer you received, it's not good), to open a **new question**, provide a code attempt (with the `Set<String> personId`) and thorough problem description.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I asked it as a new question. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522647/java-stream-cannot-calculate-total-value-after-grouping-and-filtering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249791/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-qwercan).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I still couldn't solve the issue even if the answer of the post can be tried. How can I do that? Can you help me?